# lua Regular expression for matching key phrase with value adopted from PHP

Tags: php, regex, lua, scripting, type-conversion

I have a regular expression pattern that works for PCRE(PHP) that I would like to use in a lua file.

My objective is to inspect a value (string) to see if it contains a key identifier then to grab the value.

The test string may contain various characters including alphanumeric and special characters. Inside the string is a key followed by a value:

```
str = 'sample12_3 Word [link:a12]'
```

The key phrase to find is "[link:]" and the value it must return is whatever is following the ':' semicolon and before the closing square ']' bracket

```
[link:$value]
```

The PCRE(PHP) expression is:

```
\[(link):(.+):?[^\[\]]*\]
```

Group 1: 'link'
Group 2: 'a12'

Can anyone help me with the correct lua iteration  for this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua patterns are not considered regular expressions as they are not capable of matching regular language. However, you are lucky here, you can translate the expression into

```lua
local str = 'sample12_3 Word [link:a12]'
result, _ = str:match("%[link:([^][]*)]")
print(result) -- => a12
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/b48xjX).

**Details**

- `%[` - matches a literal `[` char
- `link:` - literal `link:` text
- `([^][]*)` - capturing group #1: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]` - a `]` char.

The `:match()` function will return the contents of the capturing group here, since the capturing group is present in the pattern.